# How to add a line break between each components in Email template in Webforms

Tags: webforms, emails

I have the Webform 7.x-4.13 version module enabled.

I have a Webform node with more than 30 form components. In Email Settings, I have created a custom email template where I used the token: [submission:values].

Then I test the webform submitting a message. The problem is that [submission:values] print out the components values in a very plain way, no break line between the title and the value for each component. How can we add a line break between each components in an email.

I tried using "Send e-mail as HTML" option as well.

Can we do this using CSS/theme? If yes, Please tell me the procedure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add every form component individuell with a syntax like [submission:values:field_key:label]
[submission:values:field_key:nolabel]
Please check the Tokens in your email settings or the following link https://www.drupal.org/node/2490648

You can also modify the webform-submission.tpl.php file and adjust it for your email.